# Webkit-tap-highlight-color doesn't work on li element?

Tags: css, mobile, webkit

I have a list of elements and this is how one element in the list looks like:

```
<li class="someclass" id="10"><p>Text <span class="fav"></span></p><div class="overflow-hidden"><span class="timestamp">Sat, 23 June 2018, 5:20 PM</span><span class="delete">Delete</span></div></li>
```

When I tap on a list element on mobile (to add to favorite or to delete), the entire `<li>` becomes highlighted in dark gray. I tried adding `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` to the `<li>` but it doesn't seem to work.

Any thoughts on how to remove that background on tap?

Answer (score 0):

As [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color) said, it works on a **link**, not every element

> `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` is a non-standard CSS property that sets the color of the highlight that appears over a **link** while it's being tapped.